# $A \le G$ solvable, $B \lhd G$ solvable. For $AB$ to be solvable, do we really need $A \lhd G?$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solvable-groups

We'll denote $A \lhd G$ for $A$ a normal subgroup of $G$; and $A \leq G$ to mean $A$ is a subgroup of $G$.

I don't know if it's a tricky question. But it seems strange to me. The question asks for an example of **$A \le G$ solvable, $B \lhd G$ solvable, but $AB$ is not solvable**.

We have on page 122 of the book *A Course in the Theory of Groups* of Derek J. S. Robinson. It states that:

> The product of two normal solvable subgroups of a group is solvable.

And here's it's proof:

> Let $M \lhd G$, $N \lhd G$ are two normal solvable subgroups of $G$. Then, since $N \lhd G$, we have $N \lhd MN \leq G$. So: $MN / N \cong M / (M \cap N)$. Since $M$ is solvable, $M/ (M \cap N)$ is too. Which means that $MN / N$ is solvable. Now by the fact that $N$ is also solvable, we have $MN$ is solvable. **(Q.E.D)**

My question is that: Maybe I am missing something, but I fail to see where in the proof above is the fact that $M, N$ are **both** *normal subgroups* used?

Is it a tricky question? Do such subgroups exist?

Thank you guys so much,

And have a good day, :x

Comment: Are you saying that there is a question in Robinson's book that asks for such an example? That's hard to believe!

Comment: @DerekHolt: Well, no, the problem is from our professor. ==' And, I just find it pretty strange @@

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same proof works if one take $A$ to be non-normal instead of being normal.

One has $AB/B \cong A/A \cap B$ is soluble since it is a homomorphic image of a soluble one.  As $B$ is soluble and the class of soluble groups is closed under taking extensions of its members, $AB$ is soluble.

If I remember, $AB$ is also soluble, if one drop the normality condition and assume that both $A$ and $B$ are nilpotent.

Comment: For finite groups it is true that a product of two nilpotent groups is soluble, but I think it's still an open question for infinite groups.