# Let $G$ be a group such that $N\unlhd G$ and $H \le G$ are both solvable. Show that $NH$ is solvable.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, solvable-groups

Since, $N \unlhd G$ and $H \le G$, from the second isomorphism theorem we know that $N \unlhd NH$, therefore $NH$ is solvable if $N$ and $NH/N$ are solvable.

From our assumptions, $N$ is solvable, therefore the question is whether $NH/N$ is solvable or not.

Again, from the second isomorphism theorem, we know that $ NH/N \simeq H/ H \cap N$.

Since, $H$ is solvable and $H\cap N \unlhd H$, $H/ H \cap N$ must be solvable, therefore $NH/N$ is solvable and so is $NH$.

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, perfect!__

Comment: @AnneBauval Thank you! :)

Comment: The (much less detailed!) answer to the following (with misleading title! I shall correct it) post is a "duplicate" [Example of $A \le G$ solvable, $B \lhd G$ solvable, but $AB$ is not solvable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/587735/example-of-a-le-g-solvable-b-lhd-g-solvable-but-ab-is-not-solvable)